# wildcard * in CSS for classes

Tags: css, css-selectors, wildcard

I have these divs that I'm styling with `.tocolor`, but I also need the unique identifier 1,2,3,4 etc. so I'm adding that it as another class `tocolor-1`.

```
<div class="tocolor tocolor-1">   tocolor 1   </div>
<div class="tocolor tocolor-2">   tocolor 2   </div>
<div class="tocolor tocolor-3">   tocolor 3   </div>
<div class="tocolor tocolor-4">   tocolor 4   </div>

.tocolor{
  background: red;
}
```

Is there a way to have just 1 class `tocolor-*`. I tried using a wildcard `*` as in this css, but it didn't work.

```
.tocolor-*{
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Here's the official CSS3 site about selectors:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors And a compability list:
http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus/

Answer (score 1510, accepted):

What you need is called attribute selector. An example, using your html structure, is the following:

```
div[class^="tocolor-"], div[class*=" tocolor-"] {
    color:red 
}
```

In the place of `div` you can add any element or remove it altogether, and in the place of `class` you can add any attribute of the specified element.

`[class^="tocolor-"]` — starts with "tocolor-".
`[class*=" tocolor-"]` — contains the substring "tocolor-" occurring directly after a space character.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/K3693/1/

More information on CSS attribute selectors, you can find [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector) and [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors).
And from MDN Docs [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: Cool info. Only caveat is if performance is an issue, most CSS linters will reject attribute selectors that resemble regex (e.g. using '*') b/c of slow performance. With the exception of using a preprocessor (e.g. Sass), is there any other possible way of doing this?

Comment: Is there a way to check if the class attribute contains multiple substrings? Maybe something like `div[class*="foo"][class="bar"]`?

Comment: That space in our "contains" example is pretty killer. From what I can see, it shouldn't be there, correct?

Comment: @Thomas That is required to ensure `class="foo tocolor-red"` matches, but not `class="foo fromtocolor-red-blue"`

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been using this technique for a few years, but never realized that class^= only applies to the beginning of the HTML class entry. I thought it applied to all class names defined for the HTML tag.

Comment: What if an element is dynamically given a class that starts with a string, then a number, then another string? A plugin I'm using gives each block different elements and numbering each class, for example the image parts are given classes .flip-box-1-image and .flip-box-2-image, but the heading parts are given .flip-box-1-heading and .flip-box-2-heading. So if I use [class^="flip-box-"] or [class*="flip-box-"] I will be targeting both the image elements and the heading elements. I want to selectively target one or the other. Is that possible and how?

Comment: To select multiple substrings, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189549/css-selector-wildcard-inside-class-name

Answer (score 141):

Yes you can do this.

```
*[id^='term-']{
    [css here]
}
```

This will select all ids that start with `'term-'`.

As for the reason for not doing this, I see where it would be preferable to select this way; as for style, I wouldn't do it myself, but it's possible.

Comment: Thank you for this `ID` based addendum, not just for `class`.

Comment: This is a superior solution I voted up because using style classes for identification is poor semantics, poor HTML design, and adds extra code. Your solution combines ID with style so is more compact. I still do not understand why so many new developers are still terrified of using the "id" attribute, when it is designed for unique identification of tags, allows fast access by scripts, is supported in every browser ever made the past 20+ years, and has high CSS specificity. Silly kids

Answer (score 34):

An alternative solution:

`div[class|='tocolor']` will match for values of the "class" attribute that begin with "tocolor-", including "tocolor-1", "tocolor-2", etc.

Beware that this won't match

```
<div class="foo tocolor-">
```

Reference:
https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation

> `[att|=val]`
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute, its value either being exactly "val" or beginning with "val" immediately followed by "-" (U+002D)

Comment: This won't work if the `class` attribute starts with some other class that doesn't begin with `tocolor`.

Comment: This also works beautifully in Qt's widget styleSheets. For example, to apply a style to all labels named `foo*`, you'd do `QLabel[objectName|='foo'] { ... }`

Comment: As @BoltClock said, this solution breaks if the element has multiple classes and they don't start with the class OP is looking for.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need the unique identifier for further styling of the divs and are using HTML5 you could try and go with custom Data Attributes. Read on [here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) or try a google search for `HTML5 Custom Data Attributes`