# CSS: What this Asterisk (*) does?

Tags: css

this line of code is for the navigation bar of Apple.com

```
#globalheader #globalnav[class*="nosearch"] { width:100%; }
```

Somebody know what that asterisk after class means there?

Comment: same as every where, a wild card, the joker.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
#globalnav[class*="nosearch"]
```

means: class **contains** "nosearch"

---

```
#globalnav[class^="nosearch"]
```

means: class **starts with** "nosearch"

---

```
#globalnav[class$="nosearch"]
```

means: class **ends with** "nosearch"

---

Reference:
http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors

Comment: `#globalnav[class*="nosearch"]` is the same as `#globalnav.nosearch`. Isn't it?

Comment: @Dani: Nope. The first would include any class that has the string `nosearch` in its name, such as `boxnosearch` and `nosearchbutton`. The second would include only the class `nosearch` and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

`*` is very similar to `~` but `~` matches **only with space** around it.

E.g.

```
foo bar
```

but not

```
foo-bar
```

`*` will match both.