# What does img[class*="align"] mean in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

What does `img[class*="align"]` mean in CSS?

I have seen this in many stylesheets, but I'm not sure why it's used and what it does. Any idea?

Comment: +1 surprised this isn't a duplicate, but it's not, that I can find anyway!

Comment: _Note that this is not supported by IE8 and below._ stupid IE  :D

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13525542/1402846, http://stackoverflow.com/q/8959152/1402846

Answer (score 19):

It's an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) which matches any `img` tag class text including "align". For instance, it would match any of the following:

```html
<img class="dummy align test" />
<img class="test align-1" />
<img class="hello-align" />
<img class="abaligncd" />
<img class="align" />
```

From the documentation (linked above):

> E[foo*="bar"] - an E element whose "foo" attribute value contains the substring "bar"

This is used in popular CSS frameworks to style multiple similar classes without having to add a new identical class to each. For instance, if we had the following markup:

```html
<p class="central para-red">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="para-green bold">Hello, world!</p>
<p class="para-blue">Hello, world!</p>
<p>Hello, world!</p>
```

We could apply styling to all of the `p` elements whose class contains "para-" without having to manually type all the variations by simply using:

```css
p[class*="para-"] { ... }
```

Here is a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hKG82/) of this in use.

Answer (score 8):

It will match all `img` elements that have a class that **contains** `align`.

The spec, has more information on this:

[W3 Spec on CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings)