# Is there a way to style an ID based on a specific word in the ID name?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to style an ID based on a specific word in the ID name?

If I have something like this:

```
<div id="name-of-id.1234">Something</div>
<div id="name-of-id.5678">Something</div>
<div id="name-of-id.4321">Something</div>
```

Normally I'd style it like this:

```
div#name-of-id\.1234,
div#name-of-id\.5678,
div#name-of-id\.4321 {
    color: #F0F;
}
```

But I'd MUCH RATHER do something like this:

```
div[# contains the word "name-of-id"] {
    color: #F0F;
}
```

Is there a way to target a specific word in an ID like that?

I have very limited access to the html - I can add scripts/styles to the layout, but that's about it.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css for info about wildcard selectors in CSS which is really what you're looking for here.

Answer (score 4):

Use the CSS3 prefix [substring matching attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings):

```css
div[id^="name-of-id"] {
    color: #F0F;
}
```

It is [supported by all current browsers](http://www.caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3). For support in older version of IE, use the [Selectivizr polyfill](http://selectivizr.com/). There is also a selector for suffixes (`[id$="..."]`) and for general substrings (`[id*="..."]`).

Comment: This is a pretty delayed response to this answer, but this css worked out great - just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If you can add javascript (and you use jQuery), you *could* add something like this:

```
$('div').each(function(){
    if(this.id.match('name-of-id')) {
        $(this).addClass('someClass');
    }
});
```

Without jQuery, you could do:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
    if(this.id.match('name-of-id')) {
        this.className = this.className + 'someClass';
    }
}
```

And then style them with a class:

```
.someClass {
    /* your CSS styles */
}
```

Granted, running `$('div')` would be slow (as far as javascript is concerned) if your page contains a lot of them, so if you could narrow that selector down, this might be a more viable solution.

More to the point, there isn't a method I'm aware of to match partial ID names in CSS alone.

Comment: I think CSS3 has some CSS selectors like that, but it would restrict it to recent browsers