# jquery select class with similar names

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am generating some `html` tables within a loop with dynamic class names. These classes look like:

```
<tr class="method_11">
<tr class="method_12">
<tr class="method_13">
```

Is there a way to select all of the above classes by only using their common parts

`$('.method_options_1'+' ')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('tr[class^="method_"]')
```

This selects elements where attribute "class" ***starts with*** "method_", which matches your criteria.

Answer (score 3):

start with:

```
$("tr[class^='method_']")
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: @tao.hong: the `^=` means starts with.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like css wilcards?

I guess jQuery closely follows css selectors

[wildcard * in CSS for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css)