# CSS input[class*="span"]

Tags: css, css-selectors

I noticed this *css* on a web page and wondered how it worked!

What does this mean? `input[class*="span"]`

```
input[class*="span"], select[class*="span"], textarea[class*="span"] {
    float: none;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: [Multiple Attribute Values](http://css-tricks.com/multiple-attribute-values/)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: possible duplicate of [wildcard \* in CSS for classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes)

Comment: `input[class*="span"]` refers to all input elements that contain the string 'span' in its class. e.g. `.span-demonium`

Comment: The upvoted answers are correct in what it does, but the use of code like this looks like poor practice; I don't think the original author of this code really understands how to use classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What it means it will select any input which has a class which includes the string "span" ANYWHERE in the class name. Such as:

```
<input class="span" type="text" value="span" />

<input class="span-3" type="text" value="span-3" />

<input class="span-six" type="text" value="span-six" />

 <input class="myspan" type="text" value="myspan" />
```

[**Codepen EXample**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/EokKA)

Answer (score 3):

'*' is an attribute wildcard selector. That CSS selector looks for any element of those types that has a class that contains 'span' in the class name.

Answer (score 0):

From w3schools.com:

Example:

```
a[src*="w3schools"]
```

Selects every  element whose src attribute value contains the substring "w3schools"

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

But in your example it looks kind of useless. Since the select probably has a class of "span", you could select it with:

```
input.span, select.span, textarea.span {
    float: none;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Then again, calling your class after an HTML element, isn't exactly smart..
Could you post the HTML to which it is referring?

Comment: @Naveen Well that's a useless comment.. Anyway, a better source would then be:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors

Comment: Indeed, the comment without any context is useless. But anyway, [please, don't link to or use w3schools. It *is* a horrible reference full of incorrect information that sometimes even leads to security holes.](http://w3fools.com)

Answer (score 0):

With this kind of selector you are saying that if the provided string appears anywhere in the value, the CSS rule will be applied.

Here you have a more extended explanation: http://css-tricks.com/multiple-attribute-values/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

It basically means "Selects every element of type (like input fields) which contains class of span.

Take a look at: [W3S Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: It should say "which contains an attribute class where the value contains the string 'span'"

Comment: W3Schools is not W3C. Please don't get the two mixed up.

Answer (score -1):

`input[class*="span"]` has no differece usage with `input.span`. `input[class*="span"]` means that `input` tag that have `class="span"`

Comment: `input.span` is equivalent to `input[class="span"]`, not `input[class*="span"]` (note the `*`)

Comment: @Raidri: No, it's equivalent to `input[class~="span"]` (note the `~`)