# Select several class in scss or in other css extended language by asterisk

Tags: css, sass

there are two class that start with `post-meta-` like this.

```
<div class="post-meta-top"></div>
<div class="main-text"></div>
<div class="post-meta-bottom"></div>
```

Normally I must write like `.post-meta-top, .post-meta-bottom`, but if possible I want to write like `.post-meta-*`.

I know it's impossible with scss right now. My question is "Is there similar function in scss or in other css extended language?"

Comment: Already answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the attribute selector

```
div[class^='post-meta-']
{
  ..
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ngjsS/)**

From the [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings):

> [att^=val]
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value
> begins with the prefix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the
> selector does not represent anything.

Answer (score -1):

You can try `jQuery` to match multiple class,

```
<script>
    $( "div[class^='post-meta']" )
</script>
```