# Finding a element with a generated Id in selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium

HTML:

```
<g id="OpenLayers.Layer.Vector_101_vroot">
    <image id="OpenLayers.Geometry.Point_259_status"..></image>
```

So the page generates the above and the number section of the Id is different on each load.

How do I located them, or even a group of them that match the pattern using selenium and python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes), you can use [css3 substring matching attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings).
the following code clicks an element which contains `OpenLayers.Layer.Vector` in `id` attribute.

Python

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://localhost:1111/')
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('[id*="OpenLayers.Layer.Vector"]').click()
```

HTML (which is displayed in `http://localhost:1111/`)

```
<button id="OpenLayers.Layer.Vector_123" onclick="alert(1);return false">xxx</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Xpaths like below:

```
//g[contains(@id, 'OpenLayers.Layer.Vector')]
//image[contains(@id, 'OpenLayers.Geometry.Point')]
```

Hope if helps!

Comment: If I already have the element that Contains the <g> element should I be using // or .// ? thanks

Comment: You can use : //g[contains(@id, 'OpenLayers.Layer.Vector')]/image[contains(@id, 'OpenLayers.Geometry.Point')]

Answer (score 0):

no need for and pattern matching, you can use this module [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4/4.3.2) called "beautiful soup" with some easy documentation [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

for example to get all tags with id="OpenLayers.Layer.Vector_101_vroot" use:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(<your_html_as_a_string>)
soup.find_all(id="OpenLayers.Layer.Vector_101_vroot")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but BeautifulSoup appears to be a parser, im usuing selenium it interacts with a broweser as a person would. Thanks