# Get unique number from class with YUI dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, yui

How do I dynamically get a unique number from a class or id with YUI 3.x?

Example:

```
.reward1
.reward2
.reward3

AUI().use('node', function (A) {
    var rewardid = node.get('id');
    A.all('.reward' + rewardid).addClass('testaddclass');
});
```

Comment: Which number must be unique ? Is this "number" included in your example ?

Comment: I am looking to get the number included in each class name. .reward1, .reward2, .reward3. .reward'uniquenumberhere'

Comment: It seems unclear what you are asking. Are you asking how to do `A.all('.reward'+rewardid).addClass('testaddclass');`? Or are you asking something else? Could you post better initial code and then post the result that you would like to get?

Answer (score 0):

`A.all()` or [`Y.all()`](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/YUI.html#method_all) takes a CSS selector as its argument. [CSS selectors can match only the beginning of the CSS class like so:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes#answers-header)

```
div[class^="reward"]
```

So the solution would be to do the following:

```
A.all('div[class^="reward"]').addClass('testaddclass');
```

Here is a working example of the solution:

```js
var AUI = YUI;
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



AUI().use('node', function (A) {
    A.all('div[class^="reward"]').addClass('testaddclass');
});
```

```css
.testaddclass {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/701826667a70997013605edcd37e92a6/raw/469fe1ae297e72a5a80eb9015003b7b04eac735e/alloy-ui-3.0.1_aui_aui-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/90be22de7f48c729b443af14796d91d3/raw/a9f35ceedfac7fc0559b121bed105eaf80f10bf2/aui-css_css_bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<div class="reward1">asdf</div>
<div class="reward2">asdf</div>
<div class="reward3">asdf</div>
```