# Advanced CSS/Jquery selector

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have the following elements:

```
<div customAttribute="1" > element 1 </div>
<div customAttribute="1-1" > element 1-1 </div>
<div customAttribute="1-1-1" > element 1-1-1 </div>
<div customAttribute="1-1-2" > element 1-1-2 </div>
<div customAttribute="1-2" > element 1-2 </div>
```

How can I get the all elements with the customAttribute

```
1-1,
1-2,
...
1-n
```

but not

```
1-1-1,
1-1-2,
...
1-1-n
```

with a CSS selector?

Comment: possible duplicate of [wildcard \* in CSS for classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes)

Comment: @Antony That question is not the same as mine. In my case, I want to get all elements that matches with "1-<Just one character>" but I don't want get elements that matches with 1-*

Comment: [How is that not the same?](http://jsfiddle.net/2t8xosvx/)

Comment: You will have to do it [the hard way](http://jsfiddle.net/2t8xosvx/1/) then.

Comment: @Antony No way, these elements are generated dinamically.

Comment: I know. And if they are indeed generated dynamically, you can just give them a class, or use jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand you could use `div[customAttribute^='1-']:not([customAttribute^='1-1-'])`.
This will work with both jquery and css as you could see:
  http://jsfiddle.net/597y2e6r/1/

If that is not the case you need more complex pattern matching css might not be the best tool ... you could use `filter` instead.

Comment: If there are `1-2-n` elements and `1-n-n` elements, then there's no other way than to repeat as many `:not()`s as necessary. The filter route would be best, if not modifying the HTML somehow.