# Can not resize the icons from https://github.com/erikflowers/weather-icons

Tags: css, openweathermap

I am trying to use these icons along with openweathermap and i successfully managed to, although i can not change their size! They way they are used is like font-awesome ones : `<i class="wi wi-omw-100"></i>`

What attribute do i change to make it larger ? (font awesome ones don't work i tried!) and i couldn't find something specific in the documentation.

starter level CSS user here.

( the code: http://codepen.io/dioannou/pen/grveyR )

Comment: Hello dioannou. May I ask how did you manage to work with erikflowers weather icons? Because `<i class="wi wi-omw-100"></i>` doesn't seem to work now. I can't use id from API to replace the number. Now the class is something like that: `<i class="wi wi-day-sunny"></i>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a month old but I thought I'd tell you how I did it:

After looking around a bit, I found this solution to target all elements that have the tag `<i>` tag.

[wildcard * in CSS for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes)

This may not be the optimal solution and you are right there is very limited documentation.

In the end, I just did this in an overriding css file:

```
i[class^="wi-"], i[class*=" wi-"] {
    font-size: 200px;
}
```

This is probably isn't the optimal solution and I will post back here if I find a better way. I haven't had a chance to look at the original CSS file for a specific sizing class but this did the trick for me where I just needed to use it in one page and move on.

Hope this helps somebody.