# CSS wildcard selector

Tags: css, wildcard

I have several pages in my website and they all have the same div structure:

```
 <div id="page">
    <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
    </div>
    <div id="title1">
    </div>
    <div id="title2">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
    </div>
    </div>
```

However, each page has its name in the id, like this for page1:

```
<div id="name1_page">
<div id="name1_header">
Etc.
```

The same is true for page2, page3, etc.

I'd like to use one style sheet for all these pages.

I found this works for styling the div id's:

```
div[id*=page] {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }
```

How can I make it work for the styling of classes, a, p, ul, etc.? Such as:

```
 #title1 a
    .content
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wildcard \* in CSS for classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the class attribute on div element and can use class selector in your css to define styles for all elements with that class.

e.g. `<div class="page"></div>`

and your css might look

```
div.page
{
    width: 900px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

for detail you may visit
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp

Comment: For the div it works. But how to apply this to the following: #page a {}, .page {}

Comment: i found the answer for this here: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/selectors_class.htm. #page a {} becomes div.page a{} and .page {} doesn't change