# Escaping special characters in symfony css selector or using wildcard

Tags: css, symfony

I am using the `Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler` package to find a form with a name containing a number of css special chars

```
<input name="myfield[0].thing">
```

I am using

```
$messageElement = $crawler->filter('input[name=myField[0].thing]');

return $messageElement->attr($attribute);
```

But I get the error

> Symfony\Component\CssSelector\Exception\SyntaxErrorException: Expected "]", but  found.

Obviously this is because the symfony css selector is using `[ ]` to contain the attributes. So If I try an escape all the special chars

```
$crawler->filter('input[name=myField\[0\]\.thing]');
```

I now get empty output. How can I fix this?

**Bonus question:** is it possible to use a wildcard instead? `*` doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Isn't that all happend because you have no closing apostrophe?

Comment: no it was just a SO copy paste fail. If there was no apostrophe there would be a php compilation error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you encapsulate the field name it should work, try this:

```
$messageElement = $crawler->filter('input[name="myField[0].thing"]');

return $messageElement->attr($attribute);.
```

For the bonus question, you can use a regex match similar to suggested here: [wildcard * in CSS for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes)

```
// For matching strings starting with a certain thing notice the ^=
$messageElement = $crawler->filter('input[name^="myField[0]"]');

// For matching strings containing with a certain thing notice the *=
$messageElement = $crawler->filter('input[name*="myField[0]"]');
```

Comment: can't believe I didn't think to use quotes - perfect thanks