# HTML applying style to multiple div in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply a CSS style to multiple div elements as in the following HTML code:

```
{% for i in player_range %}
<div id="container-frame-{{ i }}"
...
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Where the value of i is variable and being passed to the HTML from the Python side of my software.

Below is the CSS style I'd like to apply for each element.

```
#container-frame-0{
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 5px;
   border-color: green;
}
```

I tried to hardcode the different values of i (e.g, 0,1,2 etc...) to the container-frame style and it works fine. However, I'm searching for a cleaner way to do it.

Ideally I'm looking for something like this:

```
#container-frame-{{i}}{
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 5px;
   border-color: green;
}
```

Where i is the same  as in the HTML. 
Any idea how to do so?

Comment: what you want is not possible with css, you have to use css preprocessor, like sass or less, alternatively you could add a class to your div `<div id="container-frame-{{ i }}" class="container-frame"` and add css using class. `.container-frame{}`

Comment: @azs06 — Don't use comments to give answers. Especially wrong answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give the div a class. Use a class selector.

```
<div id="container-frame-{{ i }}" class="container-frame"

.container-frame {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: green;
}
```

---

You could also use [an attribute selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

```
[id^="container-frame-"] {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use @Quentin approach or use this selector in your CSS:

```
div[id^="container-frame-"]{ ... }
```

Comment: "Or"? Who are you replying to?

Comment: @Quentin I was replying to you. Edited my response to be more clear.

Comment: Well (a) I already suggested the attribute selector and (b) Answers are supposed to stand alone. Stackoverflow isn't a forum.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry I haven´t seen you edited and added exactly same answer as I did. I saw only that part that contains class selector.

Answer (score 0):

use class for mulitple elements, because id its just for on element

```
<div class="myClass"></div>
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

And in CSS:

```
.myClass{
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 5px;
            border-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So, your current code is not working because id's should only apply to one element. Try giving each div a class, and then style them like this:

```
/* Notice use of dot instead of hash */
.whatever-name-you-want {
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 5px;
   border-color: green;
}
```

You can read up on this here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by others, you could use a class but alternatively you can use an attribute selector.

```
 div[id^="container-frame-"], div[id*=" container-frame-"] {
    border-style: solid;
     border-width: 5px;
     border-color: green;
 }
```

Please see this question for more detail: [wildcard * in CSS for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes)