# CSS div[class*="x"] syntax issue

Tags: css, css-selectors

Similar to this question, I just can't get the syntax correct.
[wildcard * in CSS for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes)

I basically need to make this into a "wildcard" statement:

```
.et_pb_tab_0 td:hover{
    background: #000 !important;
}
.et_pb_tab_2 td:hover{
    background: #000 !important;
}
.et_pb_tab_3 td:hover{
    background: #000 !important;
}
etc....
```

here's what I tried:

```
div[class*="et_pb_tab_"], div[class^=" td:hover"]{
    background: #000 !important;
}
```

But it acts as if it's ignoring the "td:hover" section and changing the background of the et_pb_tab_* instead of the td inside when hovered.

Comment: It is doing exactly what you are telling it to do with the CSS selector `div[class*="et_pb_tab_"]`. As for `div[class^=" td:hover"]`... Do you actually have a **class** called `td:hover`?

Comment: remove the comma and make the second td:hover

Comment: This is why terminology is so important and why folks on Stack Overflow are so picky about it. Many people call selectors or rulesets "classes", but "class" has a very specific meaning and trying to apply it to things that it's not will result in situations like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you intend to select all `td`s on hover which are child elements of elements having one of these three classes, it should be:

```
div[class*="et_pb_tab_"] td:hover{
    background: #000 !important;
}
```

i.e. no comma after the class selector, and no class as a child element, but simply `td` with `:hover`.

BTW: You didn't write that the parent is a DIV, but I presumed that from the code in your question. If not, use `*` instead of `div`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!