# Angular Material Table -Border Inside the Table

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular material table and I want to set border inside  the table, Using CSS I was able to set border: **Normal case**
[[image]
 
but when the content of a particular cell increases border of the neighbor cells don't grow and the table looks pretty bad cell with **extra content** [image]
here is the CSS:

```
`.example-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 500px;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.mat-table {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
}
.mat-column-name{
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  min-height: 48px;

}
.mat-column-weight{
  border-left: 1px solid grey;

   min-height: 48px;

.mat-column-symbol{
 border-left: 1px solid grey;
   min-height: 48px;
}`
```

HTML`

```
<!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
      The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

<!-- Position Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Name Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="name">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Weight Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<!-- Symbol Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>

<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Approach-2:**
Eventually, I figured out the solution, since material uses flex-layout we can use
CSS
`align-self: stretch; /* Stretch 'auto'-sized items to fit the container */`[Result with align-self: stretch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T6gz.png)

Here is the updated CSS

```
    `.example-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;

      flex-basis: 300px;
    }

    .mat-table {
      overflow: auto;
      max-height: 500px;
    }

     .mat-column-name{
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    align-self: stretch;
    text-align: center


    }
    .mat-column-position{
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    align-self: stretch;
    text-align: center;

    }
    .mat-column-weight{
    border-right: 1px solid grey;
    align-self: stretch;
    text-align: center;

    } 
    .mat-column-symbol{

    text-align: center;
    align-self: stretch;
    }
   .mat-column-weight{
       align-self: stretch;
    } `
```

Comment: Nice you found out the neat solution :)

Comment: For those who get here, you can also use wildcards to prevent repeated css rules:

[class*=" mat-column-"] { border-right: 1px solid grey; ... }

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes)

Answer (score 2):

**Approach:1**
You need to stretch your table cell content whenever parent row height grows.
To do that you can make your table cell a flex box, add an additional class to mat-cell `<mat-cell class="flex-stretch">` and add these to your css:

```
.mat-cell .flex-stretch {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-self: stretch;
    -ms-flex-item-align: stretch;
    align-self: stretch;
    /* align-items center so that cell content is vertically centered */
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```