# Vertical lines in data table of Angular Material Design?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to build a grid to show a kind of data sheet, like an Excel document, read only.
I am new in Angular but I think I must use the data table component. 
How can I put vertical lines in the columns?  I would need to show clearly the cells. I have not been able to find an example about it.

Comment: can you show some sample image or url ?

Comment: This question has an answer here : [Angular Material Table -Border Inside the Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48237779/angular-material-table-border-inside-the-table)

Answer (score 27):

You will get as cell when you use this css.

```
  .mat-cell {
        font-size: 14px;
        min-height: 48px;
        text-align: center;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
```