# CSS selector wildcard inside class name

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would like to know if it's possible to target all classes that starts with `col-` and ends with `12` only?

For example classes like:

```
.col-sm-12
.col-md-12
.col-lg-12
```

but **not** classes like:

```
.col-sm-8
.col-lg-6
```

I tried with something like this which is not working:

```
[class^="col-*-12"] {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```css
[class^="col-"][class$="-12"] {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<span class="col-lg-12">col-lg-12</span>
<span class="col-md-12">col-md-12</span>
<span class="col-lg-8">col-lg-8</span>
<span class="col-md-9">col-md-9</span>
```

**Explanation:**

- `[class^="col-"]`: The class have to start with `col-`.
- `[class$="-12"]`: The class have to end with `-12`.

You can find a very good overview of the attribute pattern [on CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/).

Comment: Wow, didn't know that they could be combined this way. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

`[class^="col-"][class$="-12"]` is what you want.

You are basically looking for a class which starts with `'col-'` in first `[]`.
And which ends with `'-12'` in second `[]`.

```css
[class^="col-"][class$="-12"] {
 color : red;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-sm-12'>col-sm-12</div>
<div class='col-md-12'>col-md-12</div>
<div class='col-lg-12'>col-lg-12</div>


<div class='col-lg-6'>col-lg-6</div>
<div class='col-lg-8'>col-lg-8</div>
```