# Using the wildcard CSS selector

Tags: html, css

I have an element with CSS styles, and a randomly added number at the end of the class:

```
<div class="menu-523673 control-34689"></div>
```

I want to use wildcard css selector for the second element like this:

```
[class^="control-"] {
  color:red;
}
```

[I looked at this post for inspiration.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189549/css-selector-wildcard-inside-class-name)

It doesn't work I believe, because the element is in the middle. Is there any way I could achieve this result? I cannot use the wildcard selector on the first class name. It has to be the second one.

Comment: I guess you just forgot the *

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this instead:

```css
[class*=" control-"] {
  color: red;
}
```

The space at the start ensures that it doesn't match something like `xyzcontrol-34689`, only something like `xyz control-34689`.

```css
[class*=" control-"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-523673 control-34689">Red text</div>
```

`*=` searches the whole attribute value, instead of just the start like `^=` would.

As @DBS has noted in the comments, everything would break if `control-` is the first thing, so this is probably better:

```css
[class*=" control-"], [class^="control-"] {
  color: red;
}
```

This matches either something that contains  `contains-` *anywhere* in the attribute value, or `contains-` only at the start of the attribute value.

```css
[class*=" control-"], [class^="control-"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="control-34689">Red text</div>
<div class="menu-523673 control-34689">Also red text</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `^=`, you can use `*=` selector.

`*=` css selector selects elements whose css attribute value contains the substring.

```css
[class*=" control-"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-523673 control-34689">Hello</div>
```