# Select elements by class using wildcard with jQuery/JS

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, wildcard

I've seen answers dealing with selecting elements in CSS and I'm wondering if it is possible to perform the following with one line using a wildcard in jQuery?

```
jQuery('.youtube-video-1')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
jQuery('.youtube-video-2')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
jQuery('.youtube-video-3')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
```

I've tried:

```
jQuery('.youtube-video-\\S*')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
jQuery('[class^=youtube-video-]')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
```

Comment: [this covers how to strcture your selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49189549/css-selector-wildcard-inside-class-name), however your handling of working with a collection rather than one element is also incorrect. [0] will always reduce the collection to 1 element, not all of them.

Comment: Why not just add a `youtube-video` class to all of elements instead?

Comment: @KevinB [0] is used here to get to the DOM element of the SINGLE iframe with `class="youtube-video-1"` so Heretic Monkey's suggestion is better and even better to not use jQuery here at all. `document.querySelectorAll('youtube-video-class').forEach(vidFrame => vidFrame.contentWindow.postMessage(.....))`

Comment: @mplungjan of course, though, using a single classname doesn't affect the [0] problem. In both cases that has to be resolved as well.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion @Heretic Monkey

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan. I got there with: `document.querySelectorAll('.youtube-video').forEach(vidFrame => vidFrame.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*'));`

Comment: jquery version would be : `$(".youtube-video").each((_, vidFrame) => vidFrame.contentWindow... );`