# .each loop iterate based on element type and name

Tags: jquery

Currently I have the following:

```
 $("textarea").each(function () {

    });
```

I like to do the loop only for textareas where the element name starts with dvSummary.

Comment: Take a look at the appropriate jQuery selector's documentation: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wildcard \* in CSS for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an 'attribute value starts with' selector, such as:

```
$("textarea[name^='dvSummary']")
```

See documentation here https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector for more examples.

Comment: Bare code is not useful without some explanation of what and how it achieves, possible side effects if any etc.