# What is the difference between app-root{} and app-root * {} in angular css/scss

Tags: css, angular, sass

First, I undertand that `app-root{}` represents the HTML tag `<app-root></app-root>`.

I have seen this: [wildcard * in CSS for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes), but I still dont't understand.

Why would one ever use app-root * {}?

I have seen it being used on [this open-source project](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/src/styles.scss).

What difference does it have if you use 
`app-root * {}` rather than  `app-root{}` in your styles file in angular?

**EDIT:** Changed `app-root*{}` to `app-root * {}` to more accurately represent the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to correct you, you have written `app-root*{}`. That is not what is in that stylesheet. They have `app-root * {}` (notice the spaces).

This means that every immediate child of `app-root` gets the styles.

If they had written `app-rrot p {}`, that would mean every `p` that is a child of `app-root` will get the styles. if they wrote `app-root div {}`, then every `div` that is a child of `app-root` would get the styles. But they have written `app-root * {}`, so every child (any element) of `app-root` gets those styles.

Comment: So, just to be clear `app-root{}` means every direct child and `app-root * {}` means every descendant?

Comment: no `app-root {}` will apply styles to just the `app-root`. `app-root *selector* {}` will apply styles to every child of `app-root` matching that selector.

Comment: That comment clears up everything for me, thank you.

Comment: what happens when you leave the spaces out? E.g `app-root*{}` or no such syntax exists?

Answer (score 1):

What you saw isn't `app-root*` but it's `app-root *`. The space between the selector and the asterisk (`*`) is very important, it means `child of`.

Instead, the asterisk means "any element".

Shortly, that selector means "any element that is child of `app-root`"

Comment: ... also not direct children