# Is there a way to make this ID plus descendants CSS rule less specific?

Tags: html, css

I've been using an ID plus descendants style rule to give all descendants of a div no padding and no margin. But I noticed that it's more specific than the styles in ID selector.

I have multiple divs. Is there a way to make it less specific?

In the example below the padding and border is not applied because the ID+* is more specific:

```css
#list1item1 {
  padding-left: 10px;
  outline: 1px dashed green;
}

#list2item1 {
  padding-left: 20px;
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
}

#GroceryList1 {
  left: 40px;
  top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

#GroceryList2 {
  left: 200px;
  top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

#GroceryList1 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}

#GroceryList2 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="GroceryList1">
   <ol>
      <li id="list1item1">Bread
      <li>Stick of Butter
      <li>Gallon of milk
   </ol>
</div>

<div id="GroceryList2">
   <ol>
      <li id="list2item1">Bread
      <li>Stick of Butter
      <li>Gallon of milk
   </ol>
</div>
```

Without switching to classes is there a way to select all descendants of a div where a regular ID selector is more specific?

Comment: Try to use classes?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss It's for a unique use case and I want to know it's possible for knowings sake. ;)

Comment: I understand that, my comment was more of a general statement as I have noticed when an ID is used in CSS things often get complex to maintain etc.  Not a bad question, and my comment was simply that, a comment regarding the generalities in this regard. I did up vote the question as I did think it adds to the general knowledge base.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss With ID's it does get more complex and it can break easier. But in my case I have a ID dictionary. So I can manage it and create new ID's at will. I can also switch to classes but that adds some complexity that have to prioritize for now.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an attribute selector beginning with the `GroceryList` string (but not the number after the string).

```
[id^=GroceryList] * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}
```

This would not override the more specific padding rules you've defined.

```css
#list1item1 {
  padding-left: 10px;
  outline: 1px dashed green;
}

#list2item1 {
  padding-left: 20px;
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
}

#GroceryList1 {
  left: 40px;
  top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

#GroceryList2 {
  left: 200px;
  top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

[id^=GroceryList] * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="GroceryList1">
   <ol>
      <li id="list1item1">Bread
      <li>Stick of Butter
      <li>Gallon of milk
   </ol>
</div>

<div id="GroceryList2">
   <ol>
      <li id="list2item1">Bread
      <li>Stick of Butter
      <li>Gallon of milk
   </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Agreed! And this (the way you have it): `[id^=GroceryList]` is better than this (the way I have it): `div[id^=GroceryList]` IMO :)

Comment: @Frish Yah, since `id`s must be unique, including the selector in front of the rule seems superfluous.

Comment: The [id^=GroceryList] * is to match a value starting with `GroceryList` so that it matches both correct? If I wanted to target each `div` specifically I would use `[id=GroceryList1] *` and `[id=GroceryList2] *` correct?

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Everything in your comment is correct.

Answer (score 1):

1. Wildcard selector: `[id^="GroceryList"]`
2. first-of-type selctor: `li:first-of-type`

All together now!

```css
#GroceryList1 {
  left: 40px;
  top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

#GroceryList2 {
  left: 200px;
  top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

/* now overridden by below selector */
[id^="GroceryList"] * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}

[id^="GroceryList"] ol li:first-of-type {
  padding-left: 10px;
  outline: 1px dashed green;
}

/* override rule above */
#list2item1 {
  padding-left: 20px;
  outline: 1px dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="GroceryList1">
   <ol>
      <li id="list1item1">Bread
      <li>Stick of Butter
      <li>Gallon of milk
   </ol>
</div>

<div id="GroceryList2">
   <ol>
      <li id="list2item1">Bread
      <li>Stick of Butter
      <li>Gallon of milk
   </ol>
</div>
```

With help from this [SO: wildcard * in CSS for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes)

Comment: What reason do you use the first of type selector?

Comment: If the pattern of ids on the first list element of Grocery list persists, then you can use `first-of-type` so you don't have to style the ids. If you ever have something like `id="list3item2"`, then of course this will not work. You could then use `nth-of-type`!