# For loop repeats each loop onto the next

Tags: javascript, html, function, loops, output

I am trying to dynamically adjust the `document.getElementById(divID)` by using a loop. This seems to work...sorta

It keeps looping as you will see in the screenshot below.

```
let searchresult = function(response) {
    let output ="";
    for (let j = 0; j < response.length; j++) {
        let divID = response[j].resortcode + 'results';
        let container = document.getElementById(divID);

        output +=
            `
            <div class="${response[j].resortcode} ${response[j].roomcode}">
            </div>
            `;
        console.log(container);
        $(container).html(output);
    }
};
```

I have my container div set to the `response[j].resortcode` but I thought by using `document.getElementById(divID)` that it would only allow that resort code inside of a div with a corresponding `resortcode`
Notice it is also looping the `getElementByID` more than once.
[image]

I would like the output going to a premade div id in my html file (which it does, it just keeps repeating). Then loop the results `<div class=${response[j].resortcode}"></div>` into the corresponding premade div. Here is a photoshopped version of the desired result:
[image]

EDIT: Adding console of original response.
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `output` is added upon every iteration and never reset, so when you set the html to `output`, it contains every previous iteration.

You can fix this by getting the innerHTML and adding onto instead of having an `output` variable.

You can also store the `resortcode` into a [Set  (a special kind of array that does not allow duplication of elements)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and then `console.log` out those containers at the end.

```js
let searchresult = function(response) {
    let resortCodes = new Set();
    for (let j = 0; j < response.length; j++) {
        resortCodes.add(response[j].resortcode); // add only happens if the resortcode isn't already in resortCodes
        let divID = response[j].resortcode + 'results';
        let container = document.getElementById(divID);

        container.innerHTML += `
            <div class="${response[j].resortcode}">
            <div class="roominfo"><p class="roomtitle"> ${response[j].roomname} - ${response[j].viewname}</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            `;
    }

    resortCodes.forEach(function (resortCode) {
        console.log(document.getElementById(resortCode + "results"));
    };
};
```

Comment: I tried this, but it stops each room within the resort loop. I have edited my question in hopes to clarify things. But, when I move output within my for loop, it only grabs 1 room at each resort and just loops through that.

Comment: @BunsenHoneydew After rereading your question, I think I found what you want. Editing my answer right now (might take a while)

Comment: @BunsenHoneydew I'm done now, please check the modified answer

Comment: I may be overlooking something, but it isn't outputting anything. In the console log, nor within my html. Your description sounds like that would do it though.

Comment: Did you refresh or whatever you would need to do to reset everything (including replacing the old function with this new function)? Try adding a `console.log("start")` and `console.log("end")` at the beginning and end of the function, as well as `console.log(i, response[j].resortcode)` inside of the first `for` loop and see what happens.

Comment: I fixed the code inside the `forEach` function, I forgot to add `"results"` to the end of the `resortCode`,,, but that shouldn't have effected the modifcation to the html itself

Comment: Yes, anything beyond ``` for (let j = 0; j < response.length; j++) {``` will not output to the console. If I place ```console.log``` before that line then ```console.log(response``` works.

Comment: Can you see what happens when you `console.log(response.length)` before the loop? If it's 0 or undefined or something like that, that could be the problem.

Comment: undefined is what it returns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233589/discussion-between-samathingamajig-and-bunsen-honeydew).

Comment: I ran into an issue: because we removed ```containter = "";``` the result no longer clear each time I hit the search button. Where could I add this to clear my previous results on each request? Currently, it is just adding more divs to the bottom of the already searched div results. @Samathingamajig

Comment: To clear all the results containers, you first need to change something: Change the format from `RESCODEresults` to `results-RESCODE` (`SSRresults` to `results-SSR`). That way, you can use a special selector to select every div that has a class that starts with `results-`, `div[class^="results-"], div[class*=" results-"]`. **You also have to change some of the code in my answer to change to the new format**. You can then make a function that clears all of the results containers. See http://jsfiddle.net/msqgejra/ for an example. (Based off of  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5110337/12101554)

Comment: I got it! I attached the ```onclick="clearAllResults"``` to my search button that triggers my ajax request. That seems to be working... Thank you again, you are a lifesaver.