# CSS styling determined by variable (number) in class name

Tags: css

Is it possible to filter in css based on class name containing numbers?
Part of my html consists of code from external source which looks something like this:

```
<g>
   <circle r="7" class="actor-0" cy="60" cx="20"></circle>
   <circle r="7" class="actor-1" cy="60" cx="20"></circle>
</g>
...
<g>
   ...
   <circle r="7" class="actor-2" cy="60" cx="20"></circle>
</g>
...
<g>
   <circle r="7" class="actor-1" cy="60" cx="20"></circle>
   <circle r="7" class="actor-2" cy="60" cx="20"></circle>
</g>
```

The numbers in actor names just keep increasing. I need to style them in some way and I would like to have them repeat colors for every n actors.
So `actor-0`, `actor-3`, `actor-7`, ... is lets say red
then `actor-1`, `actor-4`, `actor-8`, ... is lets say yellow and so on.

These circles are sprinkled also *randomly* in the HTML so they are not in single div therefore I can't use the `:nth-child()` option.

Maybe if there was a way to match actor and ending number of class name...

Is that doable in any way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wildcard \* in CSS for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes)

Comment: No, as I need to group different numbers to have the same style that is different from other numbers

Comment: Then I don 't think this is possible with vanilla CSS. You probably could solve this with something like LESS or SASS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution involving javascript that will grab all elements having a class starting with `actor-` and will apply a color cycling through an pre defined set:

```js
//available colors to cycle
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
//elements matching the selector (circle having class starting with actor-
const actors = document.querySelectorAll('circle[class^="actor-"]');

//for each actor
actors.forEach(actor => {

  //get the actor number
  const number = parseInt(actor.className.baseVal.match(/actor-(\d+)/)[1], 10);
  
  //sets the color according to the actor number
  actor.style.fill = colors[number % colors.length];
});
```

```css
svg{
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 60 30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  
  <g>
     <circle r="5" class="actor-0" cy="10" cx="10"></circle>     
     <circle r="5" class="actor-1" cy="10" cx="20"></circle>
     <circle r="5" class="actor-2" cy="10" cx="30"></circle>
     <circle r="5" class="actor-3" cy="10" cx="40"></circle>  
     <circle r="5" class="actor-4" cy="10" cx="50"></circle>     
  </g>  
  
  <g>
     <circle r="5" class="actor-5" cy="20" cx="10"></circle>     
     <circle r="5" class="actor-6" cy="20" cx="20"></circle>
     <circle r="5" class="actor-7" cy="20" cx="30"></circle>
     <circle r="5" class="actor-8" cy="20" cx="40"></circle>  
     <circle r="5" class="actor-9" cy="20" cx="50"></circle>     
  </g>  
  
</svg>
```