# Simplify CSS Using Wildcard Selector

Tags: css

Given the following styles, I'm guessing it can be simplified using a wildcard selector but I can't seem to get the syntax right. Can anybody help?

```
.swatch-label.swatch-black.is-invalid:before,
.swatch-label.swatch-blue.is-invalid:before,
.swatch-label.swatch-brown.is-invalid:before,
.swatch-label.swatch-green.is-invalid:before,
.swatch-label.swatch-multi.is-invalid:before,
.swatch-label.swatch-orange.is-invalid:before,
.swatch-label.swatch-pink.is-invalid:before,
.swatch-label.swatch-purple.is-invalid:before,
.swatch-label.swatch-red.is-invalid:before,
.swatch-label.swatch-silver.is-invalid:before,
.swatch-label.swatch-white.is-invalid:before,
.swatch-label.swatch-yellow.is-invalid:before {
    border-color: #dc3545;
}
```

Comment: For each invalid just use `.swatch-label.is-invalid::before {border-color: #dc3545;}`. You do not have to number of all possible cases, all additional classes.

Comment: Without context we can't know how this might be easily simplified, or why `.swatch-label. Is-invalid::before` isn't the immediately obvious simplification.

Comment: If the browsers you need to support allow it, you could look into CSS nesting. But for even more simplification over and above nesting, we would need to know there are definitely no  swatch- classes in use other than those shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for this: [wildcard * in CSS for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110249/wildcard-in-css-for-classes).

In your case it would translate to:

```css
[class^="swatch-"].is-invalid,
[class*=" swatch-"].is-invalid {
  border-color: #dc3545;
}
```

Comment: How can we know this covers all possibilities? What if there were a swatch-indigo class, or a swatch-nocolor or a swatch-big-size class etc etc. we haven’t been given enough information to know as yet.